# Writing 2024 as the sum of 3 and 4 squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I'm currently taking a course in number theory and we've just seen that any number can be written as the sum of the 4 squares, and that numbers can be written as the sum of 3 if they aren't of a certain form.

The notes gave an example using 2024

$2024=44^2+4^2+6^2+6^2$ and then leaves finding if its possible to find a sum of 3 as an exercise.

My first question is if there is a systematic way to find some 4 numbers such that you have $n=x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2$ for any $n$ you pick, for smaller numbers anyway.

As to the exercise, i know the sums of 3 exist since 2024 is not of the form $4^a(8b+7)$, and after some brute force guessing i've found 8,14,42 and 10,30,32 as triples that work. But this was me just plugging in values and seeing if it worked, is there a better way of finding these triples? I've had some ideas along of the lines if you can find a sum of 4 such that 2 of them are in a Pythagorean triple, but this doesn't seem to help much because i still have to find the sum of 4.

Comment: "*Is there a systematic way*"  Yes, and is described in the proof of [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).  See also [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem) for the case of three.

Comment: +1, but since your post contains 2 questions, I think you should split it, so that each of your two questions can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JMoravitz I don't see how the proof gives you an easy way to find 4 such numbers sorry

Comment: With a brute-force search, I found the three-squares expressions $2^2 + 16^2 + 42^2$, $2^2 + 24^2 + 38^2$, $8^2 + 14^2 + 42^2$, $10^2 + 18^2 + 40^2$, $10^2 + 30^2 + 32^2$, $16^2 + 18^2 + 38^2$, and $18^2 + 26^2 + 32^2$.

Comment: Or for four (nonzero) squares: $2^2 + 18^2 + 20^2 + 36^2$, $4^2 + 6^2 + 6^2 + 44^2$, $4^2 + 6^2 + 26^2 + 36^2$, $4^2 + 10^2 + 12^2 + 42^2$, $4^2 + 18^2 + 28^2 + 30^2$, $6^2 + 8^2 + 18^2 + 40^2$, $6^2 + 8^2 + 30^2 + 32^2$, $6^2 + 12^2 + 20^2 + 38^2$, $6^2 + 16^2 + 24^2 + 34^2$, $8^2 + 22^2 + 24^2 + 30^2$, $10^2 + 12^2 + 22^2 + 36^2$, $10^2 + 18^2 + 24^2 + 32^2$, $12^2 + 14^2 + 28^2 + 30^2$, $12^2 + 18^2 + 20^2 + 34^2$, $14^2 + 24^2 + 24^2 + 26^2$, and $18^2 + 20^2 + 20^2 + 30^2$.

Comment: In a sense the process involves being able to factor numbers, eventually making way to recognizing which integers are sums of two squares.  Is that building block familiar to you?

Comment: For three numbers, $32^2+30^2+10^2$ should work

Comment: You can use brute force. Take the square root of $2024$ to get $2024=44^2 + 88$. Now $88=8*11=9^2 +7$. Here both 11 and 7 cannot be sum of two squares. So we want to use a smaller decomposition of $88$ which can be written as $88=7^2 + 39$. Again $39=3*13$ cannot be put as a sum of two squares because of $3$. So we need to consider a lower decomposition of $88$. So $88=6^2 + 52$. Since we we can't use $52=7^2 +3$ because of $3$. So we try $52=6^2 + 16$ and $16= 4^2$. We now have the full decomposition of $2024=44^2 +6^2+6^2+4^2$.

Comment: Here's a site to calculate the sum of $4$ squares for small numbers. But there are many more methods documented in this math site and computer science sites...https://www.mathcelebrity.com/foursquare.php

Answer (score 1):

For four squares, a somewhat systematic way to go is find the prime factorization and then reduce to representing each such prime as a sum of four squares. For example, $2024 = 2^3 \cdot 11 \cdot 23$. We have $11 = 3^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 + 0^2$ and $23 = 3^2 + 3^2 + 2^2 + 1^2$. Then systematically use the identity (hope it's right; I'm multiplying quaternions in my head)

$$(a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2) = (ax - by - cz - dw)^2 + (ay + bx + cw - dz)^2 + (az + cx + dy - bw)^2 + (aw + dx + bz - cy)^2$$
that shows that sums of four squares are closed under taking products.

(More systematic still, the Wikipedia article linked to by JMoravitz in a comment gives a reference to an algorithm due to Rabin and Shallitt for finding the four squares, but I've not looked at that.)

Answer (score 1):

I decided to factor out the power of four, so $2024 = 4 \cdot 506$.  Then any sum of squares for $506$ can be easily converted into a sum of squares for the original $2024$.

To get a sum of three squares, we need to subtract off a square that leaves us with a number that is a sum of two squares.  We will need an odd square somewhere along the line, so I tried subtracting off $81$:

$$ 506 - 81 = 5^2 \cdot 17 = 5^2 + 20^2 $$

Then $2024 = 4(9^2 + 5^2 + 20^2)$ gives us a sum of three squares.  Also $5^2 = 3^2 + 4^2$ is a well-known Pythagorean triple, so sum of four squares quickly follows.